# mysql views my query output i need different manner

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
Select Count(Case When campaign_pid != 0 Then 1 End) 
   As Email, Count(Case When sms_pid != 0 Then 1 End) 
   As Sms, Count(Case When survey_pid != 0 Then 1 End) 
   As Survey From tablename
```

Please help me This is my query output

```
Email   Sms     Survey    
21      1       4
```

i need output like this

```
 name    value  
 Email   21  
 Sms     1   
 Survey  4
```

Please tell me how to get like above optput

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work

```
SELECT 'Email' AS Name, Count(Case When campaign_pid != 0 Then 1 End) As Value From tablename
 UNION SELECT 'SMS', Count(Case When sms_pid != 0 Then 1 End)s  From tablename
 UNION SELECT 'Survey', Count(Case When survey_pid != 0 Then 1 End) From tablename
```

or better still

```
SELECT 'Email' AS Name, COUNT() AS Value FROM tablename WHERE campaign_pid <> 0
 UNION SELECT 'SMS', COUNT() FROM tablename WHERE sms_pid <> 0
 UNION SELECT 'Survey', COUNT() FROM tablename  WHERE survey_pid <> 0
```

Not 100% sure of your additional question, maybe this is what you want

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT some_unique_col)
  FROM table_name
 WHERE campaign_pid <> 0
   AND sms_pid <> 0
   AND survey_pid <> 0
```

Maybe you want SUM instead of COUNT, if you could provide some sample data and expected results from that it would help